# Get Data From webpages_OAuthMembership Table ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, entity-framework-5

I'm using ASP.net MVC 4 with Entity Framework 5. I've activated oauth membership of ASP.net. The template created tables for oauth membership. These tables aren't accessable from EF context. I'm trying to get data from oauth membership table 'webpages_OAuthMembership'.

So how can I get a row from oauth tables that aren't accessable from EF context without an extra SqlConnection or do you think I should migrate this table to ef context (but how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **database-first** approach, go through the following:

1) Open your model .edmx file in designer.

2) Right-click any where and click `Update model from database`

3) In the popup window, in `Add` tab, expand the `Tables` node.

4) Only select this table to be added: `webpages_OAuthMembership` and click Finish.

5) Save your model and then add this line to your dbcontext:

```
public DbSet<webpages_OAuthMembership> webpages_OAuthMembership { get; set; }
```

Now, you're done and you can simply query that entity like any other entity:

```
var pID = "...";
var provider = db.webpages_OAuthMembership.Find(pID);
```

If you're using **code-first** approach, one way is to perform sql commands by dbcontext to database:

1) Add create a class to represend oauth:

```
public class OAuth
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

2) Perform a select query to retrieve providers info:

```
var providers = dbctx.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(OAuth), "raw sql query", null);
```

By performing this query, you'll get a `IEnumerable<OAuth>` collection of data.

Comment: Using code first but I added too .edmx I retrieved only webpages_OAuthMembership. It's not good there will be more than one connection.

Comment: @SerhatKoroglu - Another connection? why? You just add that entity to your existing .edmx file

Comment: I'm using Code first so I don't have a edmx file, do I? I added an additional one for existing db table.